# Is there a VBA function to run countif based on a dynamic date range? Starting date is using a variable "mydate."

Tags: excel, vba

I'm putting together some VBA code to run a macro on a file in Excel. One field is for pulling the count of lines that fall within a specific date range. The range is starting from the variable "mydate" going back to 6 months prior. Mydate is being pulled from the file path name.

I tried using the macro recorder and copied the code over, but the code is date specific and doesn't utilize a variable. I tried changing the start date to the variable, but that isn't giving me the response I want.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Range("A2").Value = "Total FG"
Range("A3").Value = "Total out of stock"
Range("A4").Value = "Total out of stock intro past 6 months (included in 
Total out of stock"
Range("A5").Value = "Total out of stock less past 6 monnths introductions"
Range("A6").Value = "Percentage in stock not included new introductions"
Range("A7").Value = "Items in Transit"
Range("A8").Value = "Percentage in stock including items in transit"

Dim MyPath As String, mps As Variant, mps_temp As String, mydate As Date, 
i As Integer

MyPath = "C:\Users\Kirank\Documents\Stock Feed 
Analysis\HVL_Available_to_Sell_Report_with_Headers 2019.01.01"
mps = Split(MyPath, " ")

For i = LBound(mps) To UBound(mps)
    mps_temp = mps(UBound(mps) - i)
    If mps_temp Like "####.##.##" Then
        mydate = DateSerial(Mid(mps_temp, 1, 4), Mid(mps_temp, 6, 2), 
Mid(mps_temp, 9, 2))
        Exit For
    End If
Next
Range("B1").Value = mydate

    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = 
"=COUNT(HVL_Available_to_Sell_Report_wi!C[3])"
    Range("B3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = 
"=COUNTIF(HVL_Available_to_Sell_Report_wi!C[3],0)"
    Range("B4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = 
"=COUNTIF(HVL_Available_to_Sell_Report_wi!C[13],"">=mydate-181"")"
    Range("B5").Select

End Sub
```

[Output from query above screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sozvD.png)

Output for Row 4 should be 131 based on simple filtering.The response I'm getting back thus far has been "1."

[Source Data screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XX1wt.png)

Column that query is referencing is column O - UDF_INTRODUCED

Comment: "...but that isn't giving me the response I want." - What *is* it giving you? An error? Incorrect returned data? Can you post a sample of the input and expected result?

Comment: We need more info here. What are some sample file names so we can figure out how to extract the date. What range do you want to count (what columns or rows)? & what criteria (from file name date back to 6 months)?

Comment: Apologies, yeah, I'll add in that information. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Shouldn't the >= be to the left of the double quote?

Comment: Since you already put mydate in B1 and currently in B4 could you use:
"=COUNTIF(HVL_Available_to_Sell_Report_wi!C[13],>=R[-3]C -181)"

Comment: Jan - when I put the ">=" outside of the double quote, I get a Run-time error '1004'

However, when I make the suggested edit, the data is still coming back with the same response of "1"

Comment: The correct syntax is: `"=COUNTIF(HVL_Available_to_Sell_Report_wi!C[13],"">=" & mydate - 181 & """)"`